# logrotation - rotate and maxage command

Tags: logrotate

Can anybody please explain me about the function of 'rotate' and 'maxage' in logrotation as this is very confusing .

consider am using the below values in my script:

```
rotate 30
maxage 30
```

Thank you..

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Both of them define how many logfiles you want to keep. While `rotate` accepts a number of files, `maxage` will parse its value as a time. So if you rotate your log weekly you can either use `rotate 2` or `maxage 14`.
Keep in mind that `maxage` will delete old log files after the given time so if there are no new log entries, logrotate will not create new archives but it will delete the old ones while rotate won't do that.

The best option is to combine both of them:

```
weekly
rotate 4
maxage 60
```

This will rotate the log file every week and there won't be more than 4 archives (one month). But if the files are older than 60 days, logrotate will remove them.

Comment: /data_gpfs/engageone/active-drive/E-Archive/SystemData/logrotation_test/test.log {
        daily
        copytruncate
        create 775 root wsdepl
        dateext
  dateformat .%Y.%m.%d
        rotate 30
  maxage 30
        missingok
        #notifempty
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
           cd /data_gpfs/engageone/active-drive/E-Archive/SystemData/logrotation_test
           gzip test.log.*
           mv /data_gpfs/engageone/active-drive/E-Archive/SystemData/logrotation_test/*.gz /data_gpfs/engageone/active-drive/E-Archive/SystemData/logrotation_test/backup
        endscript
}

Comment: please check the above script where I have to rotate the file for 30 days and is moved into the backup directory after rotation.. so as I have used rotate 30 and maxage 30, will the oldest file be deleted after 30 days..?