# Using maxage in conjuction with rotate in logrotate?

Tags: logs, logrotate

I've read these blogs about maxage and rotate when used in conjunction and I'm still confused about it.

https://www.clearos.com/clearfoundation/social/community/silly-question-re-logrotate-and-rotate-vs-maxage

[logrotation - rotate and maxage command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/261696/logrotation-rotate-and-maxage-command)

https://www.net7.be/blog/article/configuring_logrotate.html

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/logrotate.8.html

I imagine a scenario like this.

```
{
    daily
    rotate 10
    maxage 5

}

First day:
application.log 


rotation_count=1<10=>do nothing
age_of_oldest_log=0 days<5=>do nothing

Second day:
application.log 
application.log_first_day

rotation_count=2<10=>do nothing
age_of_oldest_log=1 days<5=>do nothing

Third day:
application.log
application.log_first_day
application.log_second_day

rotation_count=3<10=>do nothing
age_of_oldest_log=2 days<5=>do nothing


Fourth day:
application.log
application.log_first_day
application.log_second_day
application.log_third_day

rotation_count=4<10=>do nothing
age_of_oldest_log=3 days<5=>do nothing


Fifth day:
application.log
application.log_first_day
application.log_second_day
application.log_third_day
application.log_fourth_day

rotation_count=5<10=>do nothing
age_of_oldest_log=4 days<5=>do nothing


Sixth day:
application.log
application.log_first_day
application.log_second_day
application.log_third_day
application.log_fourth_day
application.log_fifth_day

rotation_count=6<10 =>do nothing
age_of_oldest_log=5 days!<5=>delete the oldest log application.log_first_day




Seventh day:
application.log
application.log_second_day
application.log_third_day
application.log_fourth_day
application.log_fifth_day
application.log_sixth_day

rotation_count=7<10 => do nothing
age_of_oldest_log=5!<5=>delete the oldest log application.log_second_day

Eighth day:
application.log
application.log_third_day
application.log_fourth_day
application.log_fifth_day
application.log_sixth_day
application.log_seventh_day

rotation_count=8<10=>do nothing
age_of_oldest_log=5!<5=>delete the oldest log application.log_third_day

Ninth day:
application.log
application.log_fifth_day
application.log_sixth_day
application.log_seventh_day
application.log_eighth_day

rotation_count=9<10=>do nothing
age_of_oldest_log=5!<5=>delete the oldest log application.log_fourth_day


Tenth day:
application.log
application.log_seventh_day
application.log_eighth_day
application.log_ninth_day

rotation_count=10!<10=>remove the oldest file after 10 rotations thusremove application.log_fifth_day
age_of_oldest_log=4!<5=>do nothing.

Eleventh day:
application.log
application.log_eighth_day
application.log_ninth_day
application.log_ninth_day 

rotation_count=11!<10=>remove the oldest log file ie application.log_seventh_day
age_of_oldest_log=3<5=>do nothing.


Is this how it works? Or am I missing something?
```

Comment: Gut conjecture: it mostly doesn't make sense to have both if know your file will be rotated every time (i.e. no `minsize`, `notifempty`), you could just as well write `rotate 5`. Border case might be something like `weekly; rotate 5; maxage 30` where the oldest file might get deleted at day 30 instead of 35? I'm not entirely sure what you _want_ your outcome to be.